# Converting weekly data to daily data for numerical and Categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been trying to convert weekly data to daily data where there are 3 types of data types in the columns. The categorical ones works fine but have been struggling for the numerical ones where the data in the rows will be divided by 7!

Here is the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
data = {'Date': ['2015-01-25', '2015-02-01', '2015-02-08', '2015-02-15', '2015-02-22'],
        'AveragePrice': [1.06, 0.99, 0.99, 1.06, 1.13],
        'Total Volume': [45147.50, 70873.60, 51253.97, 41567.62, 45675.05],
        '4046': [941.38, 1353.90, 1357.37, 986.66, 1088.38],
        '4225': [33196.16, 60017.20, 39111.81, 30045.51, 35056.13],
        '4770': [164.14, 179.32, 163.25, 222.42, 151.00],
        'Total Bags': [10845.82, 9323.18, 10621.54, 10313.03, 9379.54],
        'Small Bags': [10103.35, 9170.82, 10113.10, 9979.87, 9000.16],
        'Large Bags': [742.47, 152.36, 508.44, 333.16, 379.38],
        'XLarge Bags': [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
        'type': ['conventional', 'conventional', 'conventional', 'conventional', 'conventional'],
        'year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015],
        'region': ['Albany', 'Albany', 'Albany', 'Albany', 'Albany'],
        'AveragePrice Lag1': [1.17, 1.06, 0.99, 0.99, 1.06],
        'AveragePrice Lag2': [1.24, 1.17, 1.06, 0.99, 0.99],
        'AveragePrice Lag3': [1.22, 1.24, 1.17, 1.06, 0.99],
        'Total Volume Lag1': [44511.28, 45147.50, 70873.60, 51253.97, 41567.62],
        'Total Volume Lag2': [41195.08, 44511.28, 45147.50, 70873.60, 51253.97],
        'Total Volume Lag3': [40873.28, 41195.08, 44511.28, 45147.50, 70873.60]}

# create dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataframe['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['Date'])
dataframe['type'] = dataframe['type'].astype('category')
dataframe['region'] = dataframe['region'].astype('category')

# show dataframe
print(dataframe)


def _check_for_numerical_columns(dataframe):
    """
    check for all numerical columns
    Args:
        dataframe ():
    Returns:
        list of all numerical columns
    """
    # dataframe = self.df_segments_dict[segment]
    dtypes = dataframe.dtypes
    cols_list = []
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        if (dtypes[col] == 'float'):
            cols_list.append(col)
    return cols_list

def _check_for_categorical_columns(dataframe):
    """
    check for all categorical columns
    Args:
        dataframe ():
    Returns:
        lists of categorical columns
    """
    # dataframe = self.df_segments_dict[segment]
    dtypes = dataframe.dtypes
    cols_list = []
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        if (dtypes[col] == 'category'):
            cols_list.append(col)
    return cols_list

cat_cols = _check_for_categorical_columns(dataframe)
num_cols = _check_for_numerical_columns(dataframe)
agg_dict = {}
for col in cat_cols:
    agg_dict[col] = lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0] # returns the most common value(s) in the object.
for col in num_cols:
    # agg_dict[col] = lambda x: x/len(x.index).ffill()
    agg_dict[col] = "mean" # TODO: This is where I'm struggling 
    # agg_dict[col] = agg_dict[col].ffill(limit=7).div(7)
aggr_dataframe = dataframe.resample('D', on="Date").apply(agg_dict)
print(aggr_dataframe)
```

I couldn't think/find of what to write in the place of **mean** . There I'm thinking to put some fill method which will fill the data by dividing row data by 7 and fill the following daily date data. One

Thanks. ☺️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approach that you could use to upsample your dataframe and distribute the numerical values evenly within each week

```
out = dataframe.set_index('Date').resample(rule='D').ffill()
out.update(out.select_dtypes(np.number) / 7)
```

Result

```
            AveragePrice  Total Volume        4046         4225       4770   Total Bags   Small Bags  Large Bags  XLarge Bags          type        year  region  AveragePrice Lag1  AveragePrice Lag2  AveragePrice Lag3  Total Volume Lag1  Total Volume Lag2  Total Volume Lag3
Date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
2015-01-25      0.151429   6449.642857  134.482857  4742.308571  23.448571  1549.402857  1443.335714  106.067143          0.0  conventional  287.857143  Albany           0.167143           0.177143           0.174286        6358.754286        5885.011429            5839.04
2015-01-26      0.151429   6449.642857  134.482857  4742.308571  23.448571  1549.402857  1443.335714  106.067143          0.0  conventional  287.857143  Albany           0.167143           0.177143           0.174286        6358.754286        5885.011429            5839.04
2015-01-27      0.151429   6449.642857  134.482857  4742.308571  23.448571  1549.402857  1443.335714  106.067143          0.0  conventional  287.857143  Albany           0.167143           0.177143           0.174286        6358.754286        5885.011429            5839.04
2015-01-28      0.151429   6449.642857  134.482857  4742.308571  23.448571  1549.402857  1443.335714  106.067143          0.0  conventional  287.857143  Albany           0.167143           0.177143           0.174286        6358.754286        5885.011429            5839.04
2015-01-29      0.151429   6449.642857  134.482857  4742.308571  23.448571  1549.402857  1443.335714  106.067143          0.0  conventional  287.857143  Albany           0.167143           0.177143           0.174286        6358.754286        5885.011429            5839.04
2015-01-30      0.151429   6449.642857  134.482857  4742.308571  23.448571  1549.402857  1443.335714  106.067143          0.0  conventional  287.857143  Albany           0.167143           0.177143           0.174286        6358.754286        5885.011429            5839.04
2015-01-31      0.151429   6449.642857  134.482857  4742.308571  23.448571  1549.402857  1443.335714  106.067143          0.0  conventional  287.857143  Albany           0.167143           0.177143           0.174286        6358.754286        5885.011429            5839.04
...
```

Comment: Thanks this resolves the problem but it also converts the year column which I don't want to be converted!

Comment: This solves :
aggr_dataframe.update(aggr_dataframe.select_dtypes(include=['float64']) / 7)

Comment: Happy coding. You can also do: `out.update(out.select_dtypes(np.number).drop(columns=['year']) / 7)`

Comment: Hi, What if I do have duplicate date with different Value? Then I have to add these value but for string/categorical value. How to merge them?

Comment: This is all together different question please focus on one question per post.. I would  normally suggest asking a new question.